# Do every two orthogonal matrices in $\text{SO}(n)$ lie in the same coset of $\text{SO}(2)$?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

Let $A,B  \in \text{SO}(n)$.

Does there exist a homomorphism of Lie groups $\phi:\text{SO}(2) \to \text{SO}(n)$, such that $A,B$ lie in the same coset of $\phi(\text{SO}(2))\le \text{SO}(n)$?

Comment: Two elements $A,B$ belong to the same coset if and only if $AB^{-1}$ is in the subgroup. So basically we can reduce the problem to: for a given matrix $X\in SO(n)$ you search for a (Lie) subgroup $H$ of $SO(n)$ such that $H$ is isomorphic to $S^1$ and $X\in H$. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes if $n\leq 3$ and is no for $n\geq 4$.

As freakish says, you question is equivalent to the following:

> Given any $p\in SO(n)$, is there a circle subgroup of $SO(n)$ containing $p$?

We will actually address this question for all compact Lie groups $G$ simultaneously.

**Proposition 1:**  Suppose $G$ is a compact Lie group of rank $1$.  Then any $p\in G$ lies on an $SO(2)\subseteq G$.

*Proof:*  Recall that in any compact Lie group $G$, any $p\in G$ lies on a maximal torus $T$.  If the rank of $G$ is $1$, then $T = S^1 = SO(2)$.  $\square$

And now the more fun direction:

**Proposition:** If every $p\in G$ lies in an $SO(2)$ subgroup, then $G$ has rank $1$.

*Proof*: Let $p \in G$ with the property that the closure of the subgroup generated by $p$, $\overline{\langle p\rangle}$ is a maximal torus $T$.  Such a $p$ always exists: beginning with any maximal torus $T'$, let $p = (\theta_1,...,\theta_k)\in T'$ with the $\{\theta_i\}$ linearly independent over $2\pi \mathbb{Q}$.

By assumption, $p\in SO(2)$ for some $SO(2)\subseteq G$.  Because $SO(2)$ is a subgroup, $\langle p\rangle\subseteq SO(2)$.  Because $SO(2)$ is closed (because it is compact), $\overline{\langle p \rangle}\subseteq SO(2)$.  By construction, $T = \overline{\langle p \rangle}$, so $T\subseteq SO(2)$, so a maximal torus lies in $SO(2)$.  That is, $G$ has rank $1$. $\square$

Comment: +1 I was just starting to write this up---nice exposition! I wonder whether some intermediate statement still holds for $SO(4)$ (but not $SO(n)$, $n > 4$), given its distinctive behavior among the special orthogonal groups (in particular, that it is isotopic to $SO(3) \times SO(3)$).

Comment: @Travis:  I don't see any kind of intermediate statement holding for $SO(4)$, but maybe there is one.  I agree that $SO(4)$ is weird among orthogonal groups, but it seems pretty typical among general rank $2$ groups.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thank you for this answer. Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with the notion of maximal torus, so I have some further questions. I would be grateful if you could point me to a reference or give short arguments/hints if it's possible. Here are my questions: (1) Why is every point contained in a maximal torus? (I don't even know why every compact Lie group contains a circle subgroup)

Comment: (2) How do you determine the rank of $\text{SO}(n)$? I guess you pass to the linearized problem of finding an upper bound on the dimension of an abelian Lie sub-algebra inside the Lie algebra of skew-symmetric matrices?

Comment: @Asaf:  For the first question, it is definitely not obvious that every point is contained in a maximal torus.  This theorem has a name: the maximal torus theorem.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_torus .  A proof can be found in Brocker and tom Dieck's book "Represetantions of compact Lie groups" - an entire chapter is devoted to the topic.

Comment: The rank of the classical groups is "well known" and worked on in the same chapter of the book I referenced above.  In $SO(2n)$, a maximal torus is given, up to conjugacy, as a collection of $2\times 2$ block rotation matrices.  The inclusion $SO(2n)\subseteq SO(2n+1)$ as the top left $2n\times 2n$ block takes the maximal torus of $SO(2n)$ to the maximal torus of $SO(2n+1)$.